# A verb/phrasal verb for removing an impasse

Tags: word-request, idiomatic-language

> This debate has reached an impasse. We need a novel approach to _____
>   the current impasse.

What would be an idiomatic verb for the blank? Remove? destroy? resolve? bring us out of? bring the debate our of? ...

Comment: I *personally* would say ***resolve*** *the impasse*. However, according to [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=resolve+the+impasse%2C+break+the+impasse&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresolve%20the%20impasse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbreak%20the%20impasse%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cresolve%20the%20impasse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbreak%20the%20impasse%3B%2Cc0), ***break*** is the more common. So, I will not provide *resolve* as an objectively better answer than what was already given.

Answer (score 3):

One typically *breaks* an impasse, as in these two sample sentences found in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impasse#examples):

> // But Gilbert’s request for his mother to go out and get him a can of coke on the night of the murder in 2015 **broke** the impasse among the jurors.
>   *— Fox News, "Jurors in father killer trial over cut off allowance say a can of coke was 'aha moment' that helped to find him guilty," 30 June 2019*
>   // Nevertheless, facilitating dialogue may be insufficient to **break** the impasse.
>   *— Adem K Abebe, Quartz Africa, "In Sudan, the African Union reminds us it still has a key role in tackling the continent’s crises," 7 June 2019*

(emphasis mine)

This is supported by the Google Ngram Viewer (thanks @JasonBassford for reminding me), if you conduct a search for [`*_VERB the impasse`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_VERB+the+impasse&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15) you see *break* is used about twice as often as *resolve* (even when counting the declensions *broke* and *resolving*):

[image]